# Why does Pawn say that ; is an -identifier-?

Tags: pawn

```
gm.pwn(13) : error 001: expected token: ";", but found "-identifier-"
gm.pwn(13) : warning 204: symbol is assigned a value that is never used: "SQL"
Pawn compiler 3.10.8            Copyright (c) 1997-2006, ITB CompuPhase


1 Error.
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Can anyone help me fix this please?

Comment: Could you please provide the code snippet.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It's doesn't say that **;** is an -identifier-.
It says, that it founds some -identifier- instead of **;**.
So, you probably forgot about **;** at the end of some expression.

By the way: If you want us to help you, you should show us a part of a code, where the error occurs.